# Render whole UITableView as an UIImage fails on iOS 7

Tags: ios

I have a very long UITableView, and I want to export it as an UIImage. Following is my code:

```
- (UIImage*)imageFromTableView {
    UITableView *view = self.tableView;
    CGSize size = view.bounds.size;
    size.height = [self maxYOfRestaurantCellInTableView];

    CGPoint oldOffset = view.contentOffset;
    CGRect  oldFrame  = view.frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    view.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    view.contentOffset = oldOffset;
    view.frame = oldFrame;

    return image;
}
```

The trick is: temporarily set the frame of the tableview to its content size, hoping it will force the tableview to load all cells.

The above code works fine on iOS8. However, on iOS7, only areas ON the screen are rendered, and areas outside the screen are black in the exported image.

Could anyone help?